# Position an image using pixel coordinates in Quartz Composer

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm creating a video wall composition in Quartz with several videos in a grid.  I would like to programmatically position the videos within the output window.  I'm using the billboard object to position the videos, but the x/y position is set using a polar system relative to center that has no apparent correlation to pixels.  Is there a way to position an image using pixels in Quartz?  For example, place an image 10px in and 10px down from the top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz uses units, but pixels too.

A solution to your problem would be to use the "Anchor" patch (Hidden one ?) and then the "pixels to units" patch.

For example

- set the Anchor to top-left
- bind the X and Y both to a separate math patch, to the first value
- set the math patches to minus
- as second value, use the pixels to unit patch, set it to 10
- then output your results to the X & Y inputs of your billboard